# Use mnist with tensorflow input_data but without downloading the dataset

Tags: tensorflow, mnist

one can use:

```
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST/", one_hot=True)
```

But I don't want to download dataset everytime. What is the best way to download the dataset ONLY in case if it is not in `MNIST/`?

I tried: `if not os.path.isdir("MNIST/"):`  but this way the `mnist` is not initialised. I want to use this `input_data` but only its *reading* ability without the download.

Comment: That's exactly what `read_data_sets` does - download only if needed

Comment: @Maxim Great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to download data-set everytime, you can initialize the first parameter with absolute path, just like this:

`input_data.read_data_sets("/your/absolute/path/", one_hot=True)`

The function will not download the file if the file is detected. You can debug the function, and you will know. Also, you could modify the code in your way, using the part which you really need.

Answer (score 0):

For running without downloading MNIST data, do following (it worked for me)

```
input_data.read_data_set('--absolute-path-of-MNIST-DATASET--')
```